# Re-assigning exported variable in parent shell script to run 2 different sub shell scripts

Tags: shell, tomcat, jvm, export

I am trying to run 2 Tomcat instances from 1 parent shell script by reassigning start_port but 2nd JVM is not picking the re-assigned start_port

```
#!/bin/bash

export CATALINA_BASE_PORT=10000
export JAVA_OPTS='-Dport.http.nonssl=$CATALINA_BASE_PORT'
./apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/startup.sh

sleep 5

export CATALINA_BASE_PORT=20000
export JAVA_OPTS='-Dport.http.nonssl=$CATALINA_BASE_PORT'
./apache-tomcat-8.0.5/bin/startup.sh
```

1st instance of Tomcat starts fine but 2nd instance is not able to start because it's picking the same port as 1st, 10000 and throwing exceptions like port 10000 is already in use. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try double quotes. Variable substitution should work correctly then:

```
$ export CATALINA_BASE_PORT=10000
$ export JAVA_OPTS='-Dport.http.nonssl=$CATALINA_BASE_PORT'
$ echo $JAVA_OPTS 
-Dport.http.nonssl=$CATALINA_BASE_PORT


$ export CATALINA_BASE_PORT=10000
$ export JAVA_OPTS="-Dport.http.nonssl=$CATALINA_BASE_PORT"
$ echo $JAVA_OPTS 
-Dport.http.nonssl=10000
```

Comment: Variable substitution is happening correctly but JVM is not picking distinct ports for 2 instances. JVM while running 2nd instance is picking the same port as 1st instance and failing. Although variable substitution is happening correctly.

Comment: AFAIK, bash variables don't get substituted in single quotes.